# FFT convolution vs direct convolution

Tags: fourier-transform

Recently I tried to compare results for 1D direct convolution and convolution via FFT. I expected to get absolutely the same result, however I faced with a problem that results are different, especially near the left boundary.

[image]

[image]

FFT convolution should be normalized, however it doesn't change the difference near the left boundary. As I understand this difference appears due to the fact that FFT provides circular convolution, while the direct convolution is linear. I have found that it can be fixed by Overlap–add method, however as I understand it should be used when curve and kernel have the different length, but in my case both of them have equal length.

Mathematica code:

```
mat = Table[0, {x, 512}, {y, 512}];
SetAttributes[FillMatrix, HoldAll]
FillMatrix[Kep_, Ktrans_, mat_] := 
  Do[Do[mat[[j, i]] = Exp[-Kep (j - i + 1)], {i, 1, j, 1}], {j, 1, 
    Length[mat], 1}];

FillArray[Kep_, Ktrans_, mat_] := 
 Module[{curve = {}}, 
  Do[curve = Append[curve, Exp[-Kep*i]], {i, 1, Length[mat], 1}]; 
  curve]

AIF = {};
SetAttributes[FillAIF, HoldAll]
FillAIF[AIF_, n_] := 
 Do[AIF = Append[AIF, PDF[GammaDistribution[3, 2], i*0.1]], {i, 1, n, 
   1}]

FillAIF[AIF, Length[mat]]

FillMatrix[0.005, 1, mat]
conv = mat.AIF;

AIFFourier = Fourier[AIF];
kernelCurve = FillArray[0.005, 1, mat];
kernelCurveFourier = Fourier[kernelCurve];

resSource = InverseFourier[AIFFourier*kernelCurveFourier];
ListPlot[resSource, Joined -> True]
ListPlot[conv, Joined -> True]
```

Question: Why does this difference appear and how can it be fixed?

Comment: The Fourier transform implicitly assumes that the function you are transforming is periodic; hence the observed difference. The usual remedy for nonperiodic functions is zero-padding, as Kirill has pointed out.

Answer (score 4):

A brute-force approach is to pad the signal and the kernel with enough zeros that there would be no aliasing when doing circular convolution:

```
AIFFourier = Fourier[PadRight[AIF, 1024]];
kernelCurve = FillArray[0.005, 1, mat];
kernelCurveFourier = Fourier[PadRight[kernelCurve, 1024]];

resSource = InverseFourier[AIFFourier*kernelCurveFourier];
ListPlot[resSource[[1 ;; 512]], Joined -> True]
ListPlot[conv, Joined -> True]
StandardDeviation[resSource[[1 ;; 512]]/conv]
```

$$ \Longrightarrow 2.37134\times10^{-15} $$

Comment: The term enough is not exact. I believe that the padding should ensure that the signals are padded before computing the FFT so that they become of length at least Signal1 + Signal2 -1 to avoid time aliasing